# Draw boxes on pdf and get their absolute position

Tags: javascript, pdf, canvas, pdf.js

This the scenario: A user enters data into an online form, the server does some calculating and inserts the results into a given PDF source file using [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php). I realize this could be done with editable PDF forms alone, but there is more stuff going on (like generation of diagrams) -- suffice it to say I'll have to stick with mPDF for now.

Until now I have been positioning the text on the PDF manually (measuring the offset in InDesign) but I always thought there had to be a way to do this more efficiently.

What I have in mind:
I open the PDF source file in the browser (e.g. using [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)), create boxes at the positions I'd like to draw on and then calculate their absolute position, width, height (see image below) This data I can then easily use to generate the needed html/css output for mPDF.

[image: Blue boxes].

I wanted to check if anyone had a better idea to achieve this goal before I started diving into pdf.js. Thanks in advance.

Comment: a pdf is just a file, there is no way to automatically guess where form fields would be without actually making a PDF form.  beyond that getting the pdf location is pretty simple but it all depends on the PDF library you are using.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I'm aware I'll have to mark the positions manually. I just wanted to know the best way to go about it.